# What does "it" in "it's hidden" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter, order-of-the-phoenix

Before Dolores, Harry hints something to Snape:

> HARRY: He's got Padfoot. He's got Padfoot at the place where **it's
> hidden**.
>
> Dolores: Padfoot? What is Padfoot? Where what is hidden? What is he
> talking about, Snape?

What does "it" in "it's hidden" refer to?

Comment: The answer certainly is contained in the text preceding the quoted dialog

Comment: @ToddWilcox Oddly no, the whole conversation is under duress in front of Umbrage. So it's meant to be a cryptic message only Snape would understand.

Comment: My first impulse is the prophecy, but I don't know that they really realize it's there until they happen upon it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"It" is 'the weapon' (which Harry doesn't know much about at this point).

Sirius did tell Harry and the other students that Voldemort was looking for something he didn't have last time, which Harry and company nickname as 'the weapon'. At this point in the story, they don't know much about it except that Voldemort wants it.

Later, with all the dreams Harry has, he figures out that 'the weapon' is in the Department of Mysteries in the Ministry of Magic. In particular, the latest dream (Sirius being tortured) revealed that (apparently) Voldemort and Sirius were in the Department of Mysteries and Voldemort wanted Sirius to retrieve it for him. For Harry, this pretty much confirms that the weapon is in the Department of Mysteries.

He wanted to notify an Order member, but Professor McGonagall was in St Mungo's hospital. During the confrontation with Umbridge, he remembers that Snape was also at school during the time. He tried to convey his thoughts to Snape, hoping that Snape would use Legilimency to read his mine, but that didn't work. So he had to cryptically inform Snape.

> HARRY: He's got Padfoot. He's got Padfoot at the place where it's
> hidden.

Here, "He" is Voldemort, "Padfoot" is Sirius (his schooltime nickname), "the place" is the Department of Mysteries, and "it" is the weapon (which they don't know is a prophecy yet).